# Mysql Update on Update trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, workbench

I have a Denormalized database where I have the total points of other table into the driver table. I want to update the total points of the table driver when I update the table where the points are.

Something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER sanciones_trigger BEFORE UPDATE ON points
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE drivers,
    (  SELECT pID,SUM(numpoints) AS total_points
        FROM drivers
        INNER JOIN points ON points.driverID = drivers.pID
        GROUP BY drivers.pID
    ) sum
SET drivers.total_points= sum.total_points
    WHERE drivers.pID = sum.pID;
```

But I cant Update inside the trigger. I also tried with a procedure, but I'm don't really know how to do it.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

If the 'numpoints' is available on 'points' table you can just add the delta into 'drivers' on each update through a trigger. However this won't work if you are changing the 'driverID' as well. Please try the following.

here 'NEW' keyword gives you the new value that you are changing to and 'OLD' keyword gives you the value that exists on the table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER sanciones_trigger BEFORE UPDATE ON points
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE drivers
SET total_points= drivers.total_points + (NEW.numpoints - OLD.numpoints)
    WHERE pID = NEW.driverID;
```

Comment: Doesnt work.
Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'drivers' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

I think this is because I can't UPDATE on a UPDATE trigger

Comment: Normally this is possible as long as it is not the same table which has the trigger. In this case you have the trigger on 'points' table and updates the 'drivers' table. Is this the full trigger that you have tried? Is there any additional codes?

Comment: It works now perfectly. I was uptating something using the drivers city; and thats something I cant do. 
Thank you.